# What is missing from this taxonomy  of methods used in pattern recognition?

Tags: algorithms

I'm working up a taxonomy showing different methods used in pattern recognition and I'd be curious to hear about how it could be improved. The Mind Map groups different methods based on the discipline which influenced their development.

[taxonomy http://bentham.k2.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/media/zoo.png](http://bentham.k2.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/media/zoo.png)

Comment: [Cross-posting](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/gdtv3/critique_this_visual_taxonomy_of_pattern/) is not encouraged.

Comment: Is it cross posting if the reddit thread took place seven months ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum entropy Markov models could go next to hidden Markov models.

Answer (score 2):

I would add random forests next to trees, or perhaps under a new category of ensemble methods.